# Tidyverse syntax for calculating precision and recall

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, yardstick

I am trying to calculate AUC, Precision, Recall, Accuracy for every group in my data frame (i have a single data frame that has predicted data from three different models concatenated).

What is the tidyverse syntax to do it? I want to use the [yardstick](https://topepo.github.io/yardstick/index.html) package by Max Kuhn to calculate these metrics.

Here is a sample df and here is where I got so far:

```
> library(tidyverse)
> library(yardstick)
> 
> sample_df <- data_frame(
+     group_type = rep(c('a', 'b', 'c'), each = 5),  # repeats each element 5 times
+     true_label = as.factor(rbinom(15, 1, 0.3)),    # generates 1 with 30% prob
+     pred_prob = runif(15, 0, 1)                    # generates 15 decimals between 0 and 1 from uniform dist
+ ) %>%
+     mutate(pred_label = as.factor(if_else(pred_prob > 0.5, 1, 0)))
> 
> sample_df
# A tibble: 15 x 4
   group_type true_label pred_prob pred_label
   <chr>      <fct>          <dbl> <fct>     
 1 a          1             0.327  0         
 2 a          1             0.286  0         
 3 a          0             0.0662 0         
 4 a          0             0.993  1         
 5 a          0             0.835  1         
 6 b          0             0.975  1         
 7 b          0             0.436  0         
 8 b          0             0.585  1         
 9 b          0             0.478  0         
10 b          1             0.541  1         
11 c          1             0.247  0         
12 c          0             0.608  1         
13 c          0             0.215  0         
14 c          0             0.937  1         
15 c          0             0.819  1         
>
```

Metrics:

```
> # metrics for the full data
> precision(sample_df, truth = true_label, estimate = pred_label)
[1] 0.5714286
> recall(sample_df, truth = true_label, estimate = pred_label)
[1] 0.3636364
> accuracy(sample_df, truth = true_label, estimate = pred_label)
[1] 0.3333333
> roc_auc(sample_df, truth = true_label, pred_prob)
[1] 0.7727273
>
```

Now how do i get these metrics for each group in my dataset??

```
sample_df %>%
    group_by(group_type) %>%
    summarize(???)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example using unnest:

```
   sample_df %>% 
     group_by(group_type) %>% 
     do(auc = roc_auc(., true_label, pred_prob),
         acc = accuracy(., true_label, pred_label),
         recall = recall(., true_label, pred_label),
         precision = precision(., true_label, pred_label)) %>% unnest
```

HOWEVER,

I would actually suggest to not use yardstick because it doesn't play nice with dplyr summarize.  Actually, it just uses the ROCR package under the hood.  I would just make your own functions that take in two variables.

`yardstick` is flawed because it requires a `data.frame` as it's first input, it is trying to be too clever. Under the dplyr framework, that isn't necessary because of `summarize` and `mutate` as functions already see the variables inside a `data.frame` without an explicit `data` parameter.

Comment: Thank for the answer and the underlying explanation. Seems like the simplest and easiest to understand. Relatively new to R and there are few packages for calculating these classification metrics in R (rocr, pROC, yardstick). Not sure which is the good one to use.

Comment: ROCR is the fastest (it wasn't always the case though).  Unfortunately, it's also a bit clumsy to use IMO.  I would just use whatever is easiest to you.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, the functions in `yardstick` don't really play nice with grouped data frames (at least as of yet). A workaround could be to work with nested data.

In order to reduce replication, it's probably also a good idea to write a simple wrapper function that calculates all of the summary metrics you want in one call. Here's an example of how you could go about doing just that:

```r
reprex::reprex_info()
#> Created by the reprex package v0.1.1.9000 on 2018-02-09
```

Set up first:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(yardstick)
set.seed(1)

# Given sample data
sample_df <- data_frame(
    group_type = rep(c('a', 'b', 'c'), each = 5),  # repeats each element 5 times
    true_label = as.factor(rbinom(15, 1, 0.3)),    # generates 1 with 30% prob
    pred_prob = runif(15, 0, 1)                    # generates 15 decimals between 0 and 1 from uniform dist
) %>%
    mutate(pred_label = as.factor(if_else(pred_prob > 0.5, 1, 0)))
#> Warning: package 'bindrcpp' was built under R version 3.3.3
```

Here are the wrappers:

```r
# Wrapper to calculate several metrics from same data
performance_metrics <- function(data, truth, estimate, prob) {
  metrics <- lst(precision, recall, accuracy)  # these all share arguments
  values <- invoke_map_df(metrics, list(list(data)), truth, estimate)

  roc <- roc_auc(sample_df, truth, prob)  # bit different here
  bind_cols(values, roc_auc = roc)
}

# Wrap the wrapper with default arguments
metrics <- partial(performance_metrics,
                   truth    = "true_label",
                   estimate = "pred_label",
                   prob     = "pred_prob")
```

And apply to groups by nesting the data:

```r
sample_df %>% 
  nest(-group_type) %>% 
  mutate(metrics = map(data, metrics)) %>% 
  unnest(metrics)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#>   group_type             data precision    recall accuracy   roc_auc
#>        <chr>           <list>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1          a <tibble [5 x 3]> 0.5000000 0.2500000      0.2 0.5909091
#> 2          b <tibble [5 x 3]> 0.6666667 0.6666667      0.6 0.5909091
#> 3          c <tibble [5 x 3]> 0.7500000 0.7500000      0.6 0.5909091
```

Comment: thank you for a detailed solution. Never used partial before. TIL something new.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it by spiting a data frame to a list and mapping the function to each list element:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(yardstick)
sample_df %>%
  split(.$group_type) %>%
  map_dfr(precision, true_label, pred_label) 
#output
## A tibble: 1 x 3
      a     b     c
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 0.500 0.667  1.00
```

it seems group_by is not supported by `yardstick` functions yet

This also works:

```
sample_df %>%
  split(.$group_type) %>%
  map_dfr(function(x){
    prec = precision(x, true_label, pred_label)
    rec = recall(x, true_label, pred_label)
    return(data.frame(prec, rec))
  })
```

Comment: this solves the issues but does not report the group-type.

Answer (score 0):

I used the example in http://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html
It uses nest but also uses precision as you requested.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(yardstick)
sample_df <- data_frame(group_type = rep(c('a', 'b', 'c'), each = 5),  # repeats each element 5 times 
                        true_label = as.factor(rbinom(15, 1, 0.3)),    # generates 1 with 30% prob 
                        pred_prob = runif(15, 0, 1)                    # generates 15 decimals between 0 and 1 from uniform dist 
                        ) %>% 
  mutate(pred_label = as.factor(if_else(pred_prob > 0.5, 1, 0)))

by_group_type <- sample_df %>% group_by(group_type) %>% nest()
stick_m_1 <- function(df){
  precision(df,truth = true_label, estimate = pred_label)
}
models <- map(by_group_type$data,stick_m_1)
models
```